# (I don't know what this is called.) Always on top Ghost Window

Tags: display, macos, bug

After a game crashed (OpenRCT2, It was the default mac crash window.), I have had this ghost window stuck on my screen. It's on top of everything including the login screen and the screensaver. When my mouse is on the left part of it, My mouse does the loading thing, but on the right side, I can click right through it. The inside of the window is completely transparent. This window has gotten really obnoxious and I can't get rid of it. It also can't be moved..Please Help. (I'm on macOS Sierra if that's important.)

[image: Image of the Ghost window.]

Comment: Quick test -  menu>Restart… & uncheck 'reopen windows'

Comment: It most likely won't appear but I still want to find a way to do it without restarting. I'll just restart anywa.y

Comment: For any "random weirdness", reboot is almost the first thing to try.

Comment: For UI things like this, logging out & back in might be sufficient to get rid of it (turning off 'reopen windows' as @Tetsujin suggested increases the likelihood this'll work).

Comment: You might be able to kill it with xkill if it's an X-Window (open terminal and type xkill then when prompted click the window topbar). Otherwise, have you tried using top, htop, or activity monitor to kill it?